# How to increase UITextView size and UIToolBar height for SMS iPhone app?

Tags: ios, iphone, sms, uitextview

I am working in SMS message compose iPhone app. I want to design the compose screen like `iPhone Message screen`. I want to place the `UITextView and UIButton on Keyboard accessory view`. When the user enter the text the `accessory view and UITextView size should be changed`. Can anyone please give some guideline to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer a code from [github](https://github.com/brandonhamilton/inputtoolbar).